# How to wait for an event before returning a value js

Tags: javascript, return, return-type

I am making a custom prompt that I can get the return value by doing `var = customPrompt()` and I came into a problem returning the value as I did it like this, and it didnt ever return the value. I also came across using `await`, but I was wondering if there was a simpler method I maybe missed?

```
submitButton.onclick = function () {
  var userInput = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
  closePrompt();
  return userInput;
};
```

Comment: You can't return anything from an event handler, so this approach can never work. How is the prompt invoked? I would suggest you extend the prompt constructor to accept an event handler per action which can be performed. You can then invoke those event handlers when the buttons of the prompt are clicked. If you need a specific example of this, please edit the question to include a more complete example of your code.

Comment: Take a look at how libraries like SweetAlert and jQuery-UI Dialog work.

Answer (score 0):

As Rory McCrossan said in comments, you can't return something from event handler because it is just invoked then doing something and that's it. If you want to get an input value you should make variable in closure higher where you will be able to take it and use.

```html
let inputValue;

submitButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
  let input = document.getElementById("userInput");
  if(input) inputValue = input.value;
  closePrompt();
});
```

Of course you will receive the value only when you click on the button. Before this it will equal `undefined`.

If i got it wrong please describe your case clearlier and give more code examples your case connected with.

Comment: Well, what I want to do is return the value as soon as it is submitted

Comment: And the event handler is in the function, so that’s why I thought it maybe would work

Comment: you are right that function returns a value. But look, you assign a link to the function, not define a place for value. It is  just a box where js will take this function  from when the event  will happen. And when that happen and function will invoke you won't be able to get returned value, cause it throws into nowhere.

Comment: and, try to use es5+ syntax. Var isn't deprecated but let and const work more obviously.

Comment: Wait so what do i do?

Comment: As I mentioned, you can use a closure to access the value in global scope. Alternatively, you can write another function and use it to perform operations with the value.

https://jsbin.com/rumijumazi/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Yeah i just used promises and asynchronous functions  :/

Comment: okay, if it helped, why not.